# How to handle many to many relationship in knockout viewmodels

Tags: knockout.js

I have a many to many relation in my schema between 2 tables *Service* and *Employee* (*A Service can performed by multiple employees and a Employee can perform multiple Services*) 
. I used *ServiceEmployee* junction table for creating this relationship.

I am using knockout at client side. The knockout viewmodels are create through knockout.mapping plugin from server side viewmodel. At server side i have 3 viewmodel which are:

1. EmployeeModel (*contain the list of ServiceEmployeeModel*)
2. ServiceModel (*contains the list of ServiceEmployeeModel*)
3. ServiceEmployeeModel (*contains ServiceId, EmployeeId) [cant include Employee and 
   Service object in order to avoid self reference loop at client side]*

Now at client side i have 3 modules:

*Employee module*

```
function Employee(data)
{
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
        "Services": {
            create: function (options) {
                return new serviceEmployee(options.data, options.parent);
            }
        }
    }, self);

    ....    
}
```

*Service module*

```
function Service(data)
{
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
        "Employees": {
            create: function (options) {
                return new serviceEmployee(options.data, options.parent);
            }
        }
    }, self);

    ....    
}
```

*ServiceEmployee module*

```
function (data, parent) 
{
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self);

    //If parent object has property EmployeeId it means the parent object is Employee 
    //object and we will add only related Service (not Employee) in order 
    //to avoid self reference loop.
    if (parent.EmployeeId) {
        self.Service = ko.computed(function () {
            if (self.ServiceId()) {
                var services = require("modules/tenant").services();
                if (services) {
                    var assignedService;
                    ko.utils.arrayFirst(services(), function (service) {
                        if (service.ServiceId() === self.ServiceId()) {
                            assignedService = service;
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    return assignedService;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //If parent object has property ServiceId it means the parent object is Service  
    //object and we will add only related Employee (not Service) in order  
    //to avoid self reference loop.
    if (parent.ServiceId) {
        self.Employee = ko.computed(function () {
            if (self.EmployeeId()) {
                var staff = require("modules/tenant").staff();
                if (staff) {
                    var assignedEmployee;
                    ko.utils.arrayFirst(staff(), function (employee) {
                        if (employee.EmployeeId() === self.EmployeeId()) {
                            assignedEmployee = employee;
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    return assignedEmployee;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The approach i am using is working but i feel there should be some other better way of handling this kind of scenario. Because in this approach **if we assign Services to Employee OR Employees to Service** then we have to manually update Employees and Services array and i feel there should be some better way so that knockout will update these array for me.

Computed observable may be the solution but i can't get it how. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: When you talk about self referencing loop, do you mean when you run toJSON?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution A:**

You might want to try breeze: http://www.breezejs.com/ they don't support many to many relationships directly, but if you expose the navigaiton object like this:

```
Service.Employees // Array of ServiceEmployee
ServiceEmployee.Employee // Employee
ServiceEmployee.Service // Service
Employee.Services // Array of ServiceEmplyee
```

Breeze provides mechanisms for automaticly keeping track of which employees and services are related, allowing you to do this:

```
var myEmployeesServices = ko.computed(function () {
    return myEmployee.Services().map(function (a) {
        return a.Service;
    };
); // an always up to date array of services related to a specific employee
var newService = entityManager.createEntity("Service", {})
    //entityManager is a class defined by breeze
    //createEntity is a function provided to create new breeze managed objects
var newServiceLink = entityManager.createEntity("ServiceEmployee", {
    EmployeeId: myEmployee.Id,
    ServiceId: newService.Id
}); // creates a new ServiceEmployee object linking myEmployee and newService

// myEmployeeServices now also contains newService
```

If you want to use breeze you'll have to read up on the other breeze functions, such as loading and saving data, etc.

**Solution B:**

You may want to take a look at the ignore property of the ko.mapping plugin, try this for example:

```
function Employee(data)
{
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
        "Services": {
            create: function (options) {
                return new serviceEmployee(options.data, options.parent);
            }
        }
    }, self);

        self.ServiceObjects = ko.computed(function () {
            var staff = require("modules/tenant").services();
            return staff().filter(function (a) {
                return self.Services.filter(function (b) {
                    return b.ServiceId() == a.ServiceId();
                }).length;
            })
        });
    ....    
}

function serviceEmployee(data, parent) {
    this.EmployeeId = parent.EmployeeId || data.EmployeeId;
    this.ServiceId = parent.ServiceId || data.ServiceId;
}
```

If I wrote the mapping part correctly (not sure if I did, check here for more details http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) then when you unmap your employee model the mapping plugin should ignore your ServiceObjects computed

You could also add a write function to add to your array by adding and removing objects from the Services array in response to changes in the ServiceObjects array.

**Solution C:**

Take a look at this other solution: [Knockout JS ObservableArray with many-to-many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404387/knockout-js-observablearray-with-many-to-many-relationships/11404811#11404811)