# How to design an efficient structure for knockout observables to avoid recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I´m struggling with recursion in my project.

Project is getting quite big, so I will give an example here.

From my database I collect the following objects:

Users
Userroles
Groups

Each of these is mapped into observableArrays:

```
self.Users = ko.observableArray(new User(data));
```

where typically

```
User = function(data){
    var self = this;

    self.userID = data.userID;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(data.firstName);

    self.userRoles = ko.observableArray(); // To be filled later
};
```

and

```
self.Groups = ko.observableArray();
```

filled with

```
Group = function(data){
    var self = this;

    self.groupID = data.groupID;
    self.groupName = ko.observable(data.groupName);

    self.userRoles = ko.observableArray(); // To be filled later
    self.members = ko.observableArray();   // To be filled later
};
```

Similar with Userroles which obviously is the link between Users and Groups.members();

My data objects are used in between viewmodels. I use  Ryan Niemeyers postbox-library to do the sync. Both Users and Groups are, more precisely than above, defined as

```
self.Users = ko.observableArray().syncWith("Users",true);
```

and

```
self.Groups = ko.observableArray().syncWith("Groups",true);
```

To couple Users as Groups.members I do the following:

```
ko.computed(function () {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Groups(), function (group) {
        var roles = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Userroles(), function (role) {
            return role.groupID === group.groupID;
        });
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(roles, function (role) {
            var member = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Users(), function (user) {
                return user.userID == role.userID;
            });
            if (member) {
                group.members.push(member);
            }
        });
        // hook up userroles to group
        group.userroles.push.apply(group.userroles, roles);
    });
});
```

This works fine with my structure. However I have several object that I want to connect to "Users" (userdata, statistics, photos etc.) and each time any of these change it triggers a chain of ko.computed's.

Also I have functionality to add new Users, add new Userroles and obviously add new Groups.

It seems the application handles this quite well after initiated, but at load time it takes forever and Firebug's console tells me Too much recursion.

How can I redesign the coupling of my knockout objects to avoid this?

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: Your computed doesn't seem to return a value. Are you just using it for its side effects? It seems like you could break it into several distinct computeds that return values, and you might save some re-computes.

Comment: This answer may help you with modeling your many-to-many relationship http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404387/knockout-js-observablearray-with-many-to-many-relationships#11404811

Comment: Thanks, Roy J. I´m using the imputed to make sure the array-loop is executed if I get updates in my observables later in the process. Will look into your link.